# Normalizing a huge sparse matrix

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have an array of high dimensional however very sparse matrices. I want to normalize them so that column sums of all matrices sum to one.

Here is the sample code I use:

```
bg = matrices{1};
for i = 2:length(matrices) , bg = bg + matrices{i}; end
normalizer = sum(bg);
for i = 1:length(matrices) 
    for j = 1:size(matrices{i},1)
        matrices{i}(j,:) = matrices{i}(j,:) ./ normalizer;
    end
end
```

However as you can guess this is very slow. One alternative is:

```
for i = 1:length(matrices) 
    matrices{i} = matrices{i} ./ repmat(normalizer,size(matrices{i},1),1);
end
```

but this halts because there is not enough memory to create a huge and nearly full matrix (repeated with normalizer)

Can you suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Just checking, but is there a reason your matrices are in a cell array (do they have different sizes?)?

Comment: Because you can have n-dimensional matrices in MATLAB

Comment: no, but their numbers vary. do we have n-dim sparse matrices?

Comment: Can you explain why you can't substitute this cell array of matrices with a sparse 3-dimensional matrix?

Comment: if there is more than 3-dim sparse matrices i can go that way. but the question stays still, how will the normalization be performed? the main problem is iterating over dimensions, not matrices (iterating over matrices takes few sec.s which is ok for now)

Comment: I ask because working with cell arrays is slower than matrices.

Comment: yes, but as i said, that is feasible for me now. let's change the question; one huge sparse matrix, so no -cell- arrays, what is the best way to normalize? iterating over rows is slow, elementwise dividing to one big matrix causes out of memory -> any suggestions?

Comment: You could try `bsxfun(@rdivide,A,normalizer);`. But depending on the dimensionality of your problem, you might have memory issues.

Comment: @Jacob, can you answer the question with the last comment? it worked and i can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you converted your problem to a single sparse matrix, then you could use

```
bsxfun(@rdivide,A,normalizer);
```

Comment: On modern matlab, you could reduce this to `A./normalizer`, but it's still slow (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Jacob's answer will be correct but slow. In matlab it will much be faster to use sparse matrix multiplication:

```
diag(sparse(normalizer.^-1)) * A;
```

Compare:

```
s=50000;A = sprand(s,s,6*s^-1);normalizer = sum(A,2);
tic;B = bsxfun(@rdivide,A,normalizer);toc
tic;C = diag(sparse(normalizer.^-1)) * A;toc
assert(max(max(abs(B-C))) < eps)
```

On my machine, I get:

```
Elapsed time is 6.393976 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.009804 seconds.
```